# How do I get the dimensions of an Image?

Tags: swiftui

I'm making an app with SwiftUI. I have an `Image` that has been loaded by the user. I want to show its dimensions in the UI. How do I get these dimensions from this image which is held inside this `Image`?

To be clear, I don't mean the view's size on-screen. I mean the number of pixels wide and high, which is encoded in the image file/format (PNG, JPG, etc). Before it's been scaled on the screen or anything. The conceptual image's dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by dimensions? The frame of the `View`? Or the size of the image (`UIImage`, CIImage`)? These are two *very* different things. If it's the latter, please, what `class` of image is it?

Comment: I mean the number of pixels wide and high, which is encoded in the image file/format (PNG, JPG, etc). Before it's been scaled on the screen or anything. The conceptual image's dimensions. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the Image using the uiImage initialiser. By having the image loaded through UIImage, you get access to its size:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var img = UIImage(named: "myimage") ?? UIImage()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: img)
            Text("\(img.size.width) x \(img.size.height)")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I mean the number of pixels wide and high, which is encoded in the image file/format (PNG, JPG, etc). Before it's been scaled on the screen or anything. The conceptual image's dimensions. I've edited my question to be more clear

Comment: Also, won't this just show the size of the label? It seems to me that the `ImageSizeLabel` has no way to know the `Image`'s size at all

Comment: No, it shows the size of the image in the screen. GeometryReader is passing the size of the image, through the background() modifier. Read the article I posted and you'll understand. As for your updated question, I'll update my answer in a short while.

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate your clarification.

Comment: Ah, so I _have to_ use a `UIImage`. That's disappointing... I hope the SwiftUI team will address this pain point before too long.

Comment: Also, I see! Your old answer inherently gave the `ImageSizeLabel` the size of the image by the fact that it's an overlay and not a sibling.

Comment: Having to use UIImage to initialise Image() is not that terrible. **Image** is not the UIKit equivalent of **UIImage**, it is the UIKit equivalent of **UIImageView**. UIImage is just an object representation of image data.

Comment: I'm aware. Still would be nice to be able to stick to one GUI platform.

Comment: The way SwiftUI is designed, you'll see that you cannot interrogate views. You can only modify them to create new views (*preferences* are the exception). For example, if you would like to know what color a Text() is using, you cannot ask the Text view, you have to go to its source of truth. That is, whatever variable you used to set the color in the first place. With Images it is more of the same. I doubt Apple will ever add a method to check the Image size, if you want to get it, you need to go to the source of truth, in this case the UIImage. Nevertheless, we are in beta 3, so... who knows!

Comment: I see now. And I suppose that makes sense, except when using `Image`'s initializers which use a name, because in my mind that means that the only source of truth is that `Image` (since I never interacted with anything other than a `String` and an `Image`). Thanks for explaining, though! It actually helps me understand a lot of other things!